# What happens if an object's __hash__ changes?

Tags: python, hashcode

In Python, I know that the value `__hash__` returns for a given object is supposed to be the same for the lifetime of that object. But, out of curiosity, what happens if it isn't? What sort of havoc would this cause?

```
class BadIdea(object):
  def __hash__(self):
    return random.randint(0, 10000)
```

I know `__contains__` and `__getitem__` would behave strangely, and dicts and sets would act odd because of that. You also might end up with "orphaned" values in the dict/set.

What else could happen? Could it crash the interpreter, or corrupt internal structures?

Comment: Such code should never directly "crash" or "corrupt" the run-time, but dict/set usage will indeed become .. problematic.

Comment: Probably one of the worst things about your `BadIdea` object is the fact that it is only capable of generating a set of 10,000 possible hashes, thus greatly increasing the amount of (relatively expensive) hash collisions the `dict`/`set` has to deal with.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist Well that's the least of your problems.

Comment: @arshajii Sorry, I mean other than the problems the OP notes already in his post.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your main problem would indeed be with dicts and sets. If you insert an object into a dict/set, and that object's hash changes, then when you try to retrieve that object you will end up looking in a *different* spot in the dict/set's underlying array and hence won't find the object. This is precisely why dict keys should always be immutable.

Here's a small example: let's say we put `o` into a dict, and `o`'s initial hash is 3. We would do something like this (a slight simplification but gets the point across):

```
Hash table:

  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   | o |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
              ^
              we put o here, since it hashed to 3
```

Now let's say the hash of `o` changes to `6`. If we want to retrieve `o` from the dict, we'll look at spot `6`, but there's nothing there! This will cause a false negative when querying the data structure. In reality, each element of the array above could have a "value" associated with it in the case of a dict, and there could be multiple elements in a single spot (e.g. a [hash collision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_%28computer_science%29)). Also, we'd generally take the hash value modulo the size of the array when deciding where to put the element. Irrespective of all these details, though, the example above still accurately conveys what could go wrong when the hash code of an object changes.

> Could it crash the interpreter, or corrupt internal structures?

No, this won't happen. When we say an object's hash changing is "dangerous", we mean dangerous in the sense that it essentially defeats the purpose of hashing and makes the code difficult if not impossible to reason about. We don't mean dangerous in the sense that it could cause crashes.

Answer (score 8):

There's a great post on Github about it: [What happens when you mess with hashing](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/wiki/What-happens-when-you-mess-with-hashing). 
First, you need to know that Python expects (quoted from the article):

- The hash of an object does not change across the object's lifetime (in other words, a hashable object should be immutable).
- `a == b` implies `hash(a) == hash(b)` (note that the reverse might not hold in the case of a hash collision).

Here's the code example which show the problem of a variant hash, with a slightly different class example, but the idea remains the same:

```
>>> class Bad(object): 
...     def __init__(self, arg): 
...         self.arg = arg 
...     def __hash__(self): 
...         return hash(self.arg) 
... 
>>> Bad(1) 
<__main__.Bad object at ...> 
>>> hash(Bad(1)) 
1 
>>> a = Bad(1) 
>>> b = {a:1} 
>>> a.arg = 2 
>>> hash(a) 
2 
>>> b[a] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
KeyError: <__main__.Bad object at ...>
```

> Here, we implicitly changed the hash of a by mutating the argument of a that is used to compute the hash. As a result, the object is no longer found in a dictionary, which uses the hash to find the object.
>
> Note that Python doesn't prevent me from doing this. I could make it if I want, by making `__setattr__` raise `AttributeError`, but even then I could forcibly change it by modifying the object's `__dict__`. This is what is meant when we say that Python is a "consenting adults" language.

**It won't make Python crash** but unexpected behavior will happen with dict/set and everything based on object hash.