# Why does my dictionary appear to have duplicate keys with custom __eq__ and __hash__ implementations?

Tags: python

I'm doing some Q-learning with the [`simple_rl`](https://github.com/david-abel/simple_rl) library. I've trained a `QLearningAgent` and am trying to inspect the q-table to see what strategy the agent arrives at.

The q-table (which is a `defaultdict`) is much larger than I would have expected. The game I am training the agent on only has 16 different states. However, the q-table contained over 3,000 entries.

To debug I checked `len(set(agent.q_func.keys())) < len(list(agent.q_func.keys()))` and found that this was `True`.

The keys are objects of a custom `State` class, but I checked the hashes of the seemingly-duplicated ones and they were the same as each other as you would expect, so I don't think it is that they're not hashing properly.

For reference, these are how the methods are defined within the class:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    if isinstance(other, State):
        return self.data == other.data
    return False

def __hash__(self):
    if type(self.data).__module__ == np.__name__:
        # Numpy arrays
        return hash(str(self.data))
    elif self.data.__hash__ is None:
        return hash(tuple(self.data))
    else:
        return hash(self.data)
```

I know that dictionaries [don't support duplicate keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10664856/how-can-one-make-a-dictionary-with-duplicate-keys-in-python), so what actually is going on?

EDIT: add (minimally) reproducible example

```
import random
from simple_rl.mdp.MDPClass import MDP
from simple_rl.mdp.StateClass import State
from simple_rl.agents import QLearningAgent
from collections import defaultdict
```

```
class Toy:
  def __init__(self):
    self.buttons = [random.randint(0, 1) for _ in range(4)]

  def __eq__(self, other):
    return isinstance(other, Toy) and \
      self.buttons == other.buttons

  def __hash__(self):
    return hash(tuple(self.buttons))
  
  def spin(self):
    steps = random.randint(0, 3)
    self.buttons = self.buttons[steps:] + self.buttons[:steps]

  def press(self, to_press):
    for button in to_press:
      self.buttons[button] = 1 - self.buttons[button]
    self.spin()

  def is_solved(self):
    return all(button == 0 for button in self.buttons)
```

```
class ToyMDP(MDP):
    ACTIONS = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]

    def __init__(self): 

        # Setup init state.
        self.toy = Toy()
        init_state = State(data=self.toy.buttons)
        
        MDP.__init__(self, ToyMDP.ACTIONS, self._transition_func, self._reward_func, init_state=init_state)

    def get_parameters(self):
        param_dict = defaultdict(int)
        param_dict["num_buttons"] = 4
        return param_dict

    def _reward_func(self, state, action, next_state):
        if state.is_terminal():
            return 0
        return int(next_state.is_terminal())

    def _transition_func(self, state, action):
        # Get buttons to press from action name.
        to_press = list(range(int(action)))

        # Make new state.
        self.toy.press(to_press)
        new_state = State(self.toy.buttons)

        # Set terminal.
        if self._is_goal_state(state):
            new_state.set_terminal(True)

        return new_state

    def _is_goal_state(self, state):
        return sum(state) == 0

    def __str__(self):
        return 'toy'
```

```
def train_agent(agent, mdp, num_steps=1000, num_episodes=10):
    for i in range(num_episodes):
        state = mdp.get_init_state()
        reward = 0
        for _ in range(num_steps):
          # Compute the agent's policy.
            action = agent.act(state, reward)

          # Terminal check.
            if state.is_terminal():
                break

            # Execute in MDP.
            reward, next_state = mdp.execute_agent_action(action)

            # Update pointer.
            state = next_state
        agent.end_of_episode()
        mdp.reset()
```

```
mdp = ToyMDP()
agent = QLearningAgent(actions=mdp.get_actions())
train_agent(agent, mdp)
```

Then run the following to find the duplicates:

```
q = set()
for k in agent.q_func:
    q.add(k) # or q.add(hash(k))
print(len(q), len(agent.q_func))
```

Comment: you really need to provide a [mcve]

Comment: Are you mutating your objects after adding them to the dictionary?  That makes them unfindable, other than by iterating the entire dictionary.

Comment: *Minimal* means the smallest amount of code which demonstrates your issue. Show us two `State` objects which are equal according to you, but not equal according to the `set`/`list` length check. *Minimal* also means not depending on things that are irrelevant to your issue; since your issue is about Python language features (`__eq__`, `__hash__` and dictionaries/sets), you should be able to reproduce the issue without importing a third-party library.

Answer (score 0):

### The problem: State objects' hashes change during their lifetime

When you create your State objects, their `.data` is the `.buttons` of some Toy object.  Specifically, the two places where state objects are created are:

```
init_state = State(data=self.toy.buttons)
```

and:

```
new_state = State(self.toy.buttons)
```

Now, the `.buttons` of a `Toy` object is a list object, which is mutable. Crucially, that list is mutated when `toy.press()` is called.

So after invoking `toy.press()`, the value of `state.data` will be different for any state object that was created with a reference to that `Toy`'s `.buttons`. This means that `hash(state)` will also be different after invoking `toy.press()`.

As a minimal repro of this, you could do something like this:

```
t = Toy()
s = State(data=t.buttons)
print("Before .press()")
print(f"t.buttons: {t.buttons}")
print(f"s.data: {s.data}")
print(f"hash(s): {hash(s)}")
t.press((0,))
print("After .press()")
print(f"t.buttons: {t.buttons}")
print(f"s.data: {s.data}")
print(f"hash(s): {hash(s)}")
```

This will demonstrate that `hash(s)` changes through the State object's lifetime.

If an object's hash changes during its life, that's well established to cause issues with using the object as a dictionary key. See: [What happens if an object's __hash__ changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23161035/what-happens-if-an-objects-hash-changes)

### Possible solutions

To fix this, you could do one or both of two things:

1. **Ensure State objects use a copy of the Toy's data**

This would involve creating state objects as:

`State(data=self.toy.buttons.copy())`

or perhaps better, converting to a tuple (guaranteed immutable):

`State(data=tuple(self.toy.buttons))`

2. **Don't mutate `self.buttons` in the Toy class**

This would involve changing the implementation of `press()` so that it assigns a new list (or tuple) to `self.buttons` rather than modifying the existing `self.buttons` in place.

For example:

```
def press(self, to_press):
  self.buttons = [(1-b) if i in to_press else b for i, b in enumerate(self.buttons)]
  self.spin()
```